# MVC4 add header to redirect response does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While debugging the following code I see the header is added:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Authorization", "Value");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

But it is not present in the final HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redirect terminates the current request which has the set the header value.

As it is a new request, the header is not present.

Comment: If it is on the same server you can use Server.transfer & pass args as request params. As the URL does not change the user won't see them.

Comment: It is not on the same server and I need authorization parameter to be in the header.